# Is it possible to configure GitLab.com's default shared runners?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am facing an `out of memory` error in one of my CI/CD pipelines, so I would like to customise the configuration of my GitLab's shared runners, for example by using a `config.toml` file. I would also like to avoid self-hosting a GitLab Runner instance, if possible.

Is there a way of doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

For GitLab Premium and Ultimate (os, not free), you do have [GitLab 15.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/09/22/gitlab-15-4-released/#more-powerful-linux-machine-types-for-gitlab-saas-runners) (September 2022), which comes with:

> ### More powerful Linux machine types for GitLab SaaS runners
>
> When you run jobs on GitLab SaaS Linux runners, you now have access to more powerful machine types: medium and large. With these two machine types, you have more choices for your GitLab SaaS CI/CD jobs. And with 100% job isolation on an ephemeral virtual machine, and security and autoscaling fully managed by GitLab, you can confidently run your critical CI/CD jobs on GitLab SaaS.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_4/select-multiple-gitlab-saas-linux-runners.png -- More powerful Linux machine types for GitLab SaaS runners]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2426).

---

And with [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#upsizing-gitlab-saas-runners-on-linux) (May 2023):

> ### Upsizing GitLab SaaS runners on Linux
>
> You asked, we listened! In our efforts to be best-in-class for CI/CD build speeds, we’re doubling the vCPU & RAM for all GitLab SaaS runners on Linux, with no increase in the [cost factor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/cicd_minutes.html#cost-factor).
>
> We’re excited to see pipelines run faster and boost productivity.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_0/upsize-runners.png -- Upsizing GitLab SaaS runners on Linux]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/388162).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way of changing the config.

However, according to [this doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html#machine-types-available-for-private-projects-x86-64), I can pick from 3 machine sizes up to 16GB RAM, and add the appropriate tag at the job level in my `gitlab-ci.yaml`.

Note that this will impact the CI/CD minutes [cost factor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/cicd_minutes.html#additional-costs-on-gitlab-saas).